# how to use bootstrap 4 popover in html select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Popover is not working properly...it just letting me to select an option only once.

Here is my code

```
<select name="criteria[]" class="criteria form-control" data-original-title="" title="">
    <option value="=" rel="">=</option>
    <option value=">" rel="">&gt;</option>
    <option value=">=" rel="">&gt;=</option>
    <option value="<" rel="">&lt;</option>
    <option value="<=" rel="">&lt;=</option>
    <option value="!=" rel="">!=</option>
    <option value="like" rel="Use % for wildcards">LIKE</option>
    <option value="not_like" rel="Use % for wildcards">NOT LIKE</option>
    <option value="where_in" rel="Please Input Comma Separated List">IN</option>
</select>
```

Here is my JS

```
$(document).on('change', ".criteria", function(){
    var _this=$(this), rel=_this.find("option:selected").attr("rel");
    if(rel!=''){
        _this.popover('dispose').popover({
            title: 'Instruction',
            content: rel,
            placement: "top",
            delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }
        });
        return;
    }else{
        _this.popover('dispose');
    }
});
```

please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).on('change', ".criteria", function(){
    var _this=$(this), rel=_this.find("option:selected").attr("rel");
    if(rel){
        $(this).popover({
            title: 'Instruction',
            content: rel,
            placement: "top",
            delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select name="criteria[]" class="criteria form-control" data-original-title="" title="">
    <option value="=" rel="">=</option>
    <option value=">" rel="">&gt;</option>
    <option value=">=" rel="">&gt;=</option>
    <option value="<" rel="">&lt;</option>
    <option value="<=" rel="">&lt;=</option>
    <option value="!=" rel="">!=</option>
    <option value="like" rel="Use % for wildcards">LIKE</option>
    <option value="not_like" rel="Use % for wildcards">NOT LIKE</option>
    <option value="where_in" rel="Please Input Comma Separated List">IN</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer would be better with some explanation of your changes.

Comment: Also, the popovers appear even with an empty `rel` value.

Comment: I added like this if(rel!=' ') - my problem is, when i select an option, it pop up a message but when i click again it just dropdown the list very fast as i cant select any options

Comment: And you're loading Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score -1):

It works as you have it in my testing, but here are some suggestions and working demo.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.criteria', function() {
    var _this = $(this), 
        rel = _this.find("option:selected").attr('rel');

    if (rel == '') { // ------------ invert logic for simplicity
        _this.popover('dispose');
    } else {
        _this.popover({ // --------- no need to dispose of the popover if rebuilding it
            title: 'Instruction',
            content: rel,
            placement: "auto",
            delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<select name="criteria[]" class="criteria form-control" data-original-title="" title="">
    <option value="=" rel="">=</option>
    <option value=">" rel="">&gt;</option>
    <option value=">=" rel="">&gt;=</option>
    <option value="<" rel="">&lt;</option>
    <option value="<=" rel="">&lt;=</option>
    <option value="!=" rel="">!=</option>
    <option value="like" rel="Use % for wildcards">LIKE</option>
    <option value="not_like" rel="Use % for wildcards">NOT LIKE</option>
    <option value="where_in" rel="Please Input Comma Separated List">IN</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how come its working in here but not in my page...in my page it let me select an option only once and then it wont let me chose anyother option

Comment: if I try to select again then the dropdown list keep flashing